# How to set variable name to other variable value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable: `var a = "testing_here"`, and I want to create another variable, but I want its name to be the value of a. For example, in a perfect world, it would look something like this: `var testing_here = _______`

How can I get this desired result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```js
var a = "testing_here"
window[a] = "___";
console.log(testing_here);
```

Comment: Man. Thank you so much for your quick AND accurate answer! I'll accept in 12 mins